# Convert SQL query to use Laravel query builder

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to convert this SQL code to use Laravel's query builder.

```
SELECT b.name 
FROM brands b
INNER JOIN products p 
    ON b.id = p.brand_id
INNER JOIN transaction_sell_lines tr 
    ON p.brand_id=tr.product_id
```

Comment: You can use DB::raw() without a problem

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Are you using the Eloquent or DB query builder?

Comment: @Zendy, What is the use of using a framework if u want to stick to same old sql queries.

Comment: @user7747472 The question itself only specify they want this query to be converted to Laravel code without any more elaboration on what he/she use. I just recommend the easiest way to convert it.

Comment: It says `Laravel's query builder`

Comment: @user7747472 - it didn't originally mention the query builder in the question text. I edited the question to include it based on the question tags.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following modal

1. Brand
2. Product
3. TransactionSellLines

For **Brand.php** [i.e Brand Modal]

```
public function products(){
  return $this->hasMany(Product::class,'brand_id','id');
}
```

For **Product.php** Modal

```
public function transactionSellLines(){
  return $this->hasMany(TransactionSellLines::class,'product_id','id');
}
```

Then your Laravel Eloquent query will be like this:

```
Brand::with('products.transactionSellLines')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the query,

```
$res=DB::table('products')
    ->select('brands.name')
    ->join('brands','brands.id','=','products.brand_id')
    ->join('transaction_sell_lines','products.brand_id','=','transaction_sell_lines.product_id')
    ->get();
```